# Run thread in loop only if it's not currently running in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to separate my logic (function or task) from main loop. This function usually takes long time to run. In following example `calculate()` function takes a lot of time to calculate `self.time` variable.

In other words I want `calculate()` to be called asynchronously. In every iteration first I would check if `calculate()` is running, if not then call it. Secondly I would call `show()` function in every iteration, no matter if `calculate()` changed `self.time` value.

```
import time
import datetime


class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = None

    def calculate(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

    def show(self):
        print(f"{self.time.minute}:{self.time.second}")

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            self.calculate()  # this should be asynchronous
            self.show()  # this should be called every iteration


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock = Clock()
    clock.loop()
```

Output:

```
36:9
36:12
36:15
36:18
```

This is not a wanted outcome.  What I want:

```
36:9
...
36:9
36:9
36:12
...
36:12
36:15
36:15
36:15
...
36:15
36:18
36:18
...
36:18
```

How I've tried to solve this (this probably not the best solution, so future reader please check answers):

```
import time
import datetime
import threading


class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.__thread = None

    def calculate(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()  # race condition?

    def show(self):
        print(f"{self.time.minute}:{self.time.second}")

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            if self.__thread is None or not self.__thread.is_alive():
                self.__thread = threading.Thread(target=self.calculate)
                self.__thread.start()
            self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock = Clock()
    clock.loop()
```

Program output is what I wanted. Is there any flaw in this solution? I can think only of race condition.

> I am aware that's not the greatest description of this problem. If you
>   could help me with editing this post with more searchable and specific
>   vocabulary I would be grateful. If you have idea for better title please 
>   leave it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code in my IDE, and it looks like exactly what you wanted using an acceptable approach. The only alternative solution I can think of is: 1) use a temp variable that goes up by one until it gets to 3 then reset. 2) similar idea but use `time.nextTime = 3` to jump every 3 seconds and print current time.

Also, your first code solution seems to take some time to run is because it's waiting 3 seconds to show the time. And regarding race condition, that's not an issue since you're not using multiple threads at the same time in your second solution.